# Why do I get an error when starting a purchase flow on IAP library?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

### Background

Google has recently published a new IAP library (links [**here**](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html) and [**here**](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/google-play-billing-library-10-released.html), sample [**here**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive_v2) named "TrivialDrive_v2"), that replaces the old one ([**here**](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html), sample [**here**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive), named "TrivialDrive").

The API is very different, but of course presents about the same functionality.

I have an app with just 2 SKUs (available in-app purchases in my case). One stays forever, and another gets consumed right after a purchase.

### The problem

I'm trying to migrate to the new API. Everything seem ok. The purchases can get received from previous API, and I can get the details of all SKUs (available purchases ) :

```
List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
skuList.add(...);
skuList.add(...);        
mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setSkusList(skuList).setType(SkuType.INAPP).build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSkuDetailsResponse(final int responseCode, final List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                        // I get here the 2 items in the list, with all their details
                    }
                });
```

However, when I use an SKU (that works fine when I query detail about it) for starting a purchase:

```
BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
        .setSku(...)
        .setType(SkuType.INAPP)
        .build();
int responseCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams);
```

I get this dialog, saying "The item you requested is not available for purchase".

[image]

### What I tried

I thought it was an issue with the code I made, because I tried various tests on the same device, so I tried only to purchase flow on another device, but I got the same issue.

Of course, I tried to find a function or parameters that I might have missed, but both the docs and the sample show it should be just fine to use the above code.

I also tried to contact Google inside the Github repo of their sample ([**here**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/97)), but so far I didn't get a reply. No idea where's the best place to ask them about it.

### The question

Why do I get this issue? Am I supposed to use something else in case the SKUs were set a long time ago?

Will I have an issue with consuming (didn't test yet, because first I need to perform a purchase) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot I had this issue in the past.

It's because of multiple reasons:

1. I've updated the version of the app to be higher than the one on the Play Store. I did it in order to test upgrades.
2. Used non-signed version of the app.